# subtracting from a double

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using this code to see if a users score is divisible by 20.

```
if(hitCount % 20 == 0){
    interval = interval - 1; 
    Log.e("Score", "User score is divisible by 20 decreasing interval to " 
                   + interval);

    timer.setInterval(interval);
}
```

The only problem is is that this code is in a IUpdate method in andengine that updates every second.

So if a user score is divisible by 20 for more than 1 second it keeps subtracting 1.

I only want it to subtract once if the user score is divisible by 20.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep an external flag:

```
bool alreadySet = false;
```

Then, in your code, set or unset it:

```
if(hitCount % 20 == 0) {
    if(!alreadySet) {
        alreadySet = true;
        // Continue with your code
    }
} else {
    alreadySet = false;
}
```

I see what you mean though - it does feel like a bit of a messy solution.

Comment: It does sound messy...It doesnt seem to accomplish what i need. I need it to run only ONCE PER each time the score is divisible by 20.

Comment: @coder_For_Life22: That's what it does. By "external flag" I mean "put it class-level, outside the method" - did you do that?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22: The code does do what you're saying you're wanting, and if you consider it to be too messy then consider restructuring your game so that the method isn't called again... The same with my code and the other one you -1'd. xD

Answer (score 2):

I know there is a selected answer, but:

Rather than checking if the score is divisible by 20 in the update thread, why don't you check  it when you update the score? It will reduce the number of times that you check for '% 20' (increasing efficiency) and will also solve your issue.

Comment: I'm curious: Why doesn't your score increase every second then?

Answer (score -2):

You can use a flag to check if `hitCount` has already been divisible by 20:

```
boolean bDivBy20 = false; // outside of the method
...
if(!bDivBy20 && hitCount % 20 == 0){
   bDivBy20 = true;
   interval = interval - 1; 
   Log.e("Score", "User score is divisible by 20 decreasing interval to " + interval);

   timer.setInterval(interval);
}
```

Also, if you want to enter the `if` block, but only execute the line `interval = interval - 1;` once, then move the check inside the outer `if` block, eg:

```
if(hitCount % 20 == 0){
   ...
   if (!bDivBy20) {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that it sets back to false each second when the method is ran again..sooo..this means the boolean doesnt really do anything..correct?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22: The flag obviosuly goes outside of the method... I thought that part was fairly self-explanatory. I don't understand what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: So..of the flag goes outside the method..and its then set to true when the score is divisible by 20...And then its checked again..this means that the method wont run again..which i need to run again, but ONLY once each time the user score  is divisible by 20

Comment: @coder_For_Life22: Then just set `bDivBy20` when the score isn't divisible by 20, add an `else` block. If you have all of these requirements, add them to your question.

Comment: So it works initially. when the first number is divisble by 20. which would be 20. So when the score equals 40 the method doesnt run as i need it to.

Comment: @coder_For_Life22: `if (hitCount != oldHitCount && hitCount % 20 == 0)`. All you say in your question is that if the score is divisible by 20, only subtract once. That's all you say.